# convert rtsp to rtmp on nginx with ffmpeg

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

i have a ip camera with rtsp protocol and i want to stream on the web (hls), using nginx and ffmpeg.
this is my code :

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/ffmpeg.conf
ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov -vsync 0 -copyts -vcodec copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -an -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list -f segment -segment_list_flags live -segment_time 0.5 -segment_list_size 1 -segment_format mpegts -segment_list /var/www/contoh.com/html/index.m3u8 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_entry_prefix /var/www/contoh.com/html/%3d.ts
```

but when I checked on the web there was no result :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<video id="video-player" controls preload="none">
    <source src="http://103.76.204.119:1935/contoh.com/index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

when I check the error message does not display an error or zero error

```
sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

in your opinion, where is my mistake? can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found solution

thank you ffmpeg, nginx and linux mint.

i can convert ip camera cctv(rtsp) to rtmp to hls, so i can publish rtsp in my campus website

Comment: it would help a lot of people if you actually would describe HOW you got it to work after saying you couldn't in your question. Especially since you answered your own question.